# Confuse with the command wc -l and wc in unix

Tags: unix, semantics, wc

In the **file.txt**, it contains

```
Good is good
Bad
Gp
TR
```

What I run the command

```
wc file.txt
```

it produces 4 6 23..........I still don't quite understand how do 4 6 23 arrive?

Also when I run the command

```
wc -l file.txt
```

it produces 4 which means the number of rows in the file..Am I right?

Comment: Next time take the time to take a look at the man page: `man wc`: it will explain all far better than anyone in this site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it produces 4 6 23..........I still don't quite understand how do 4 6
>   23 arrive?

It means:

- `4` denotes that there are 4 lines in complete Input_file.
- `6` denotes that there are 6 words in complete Input_file.
- `23` tells us that there are 23 characters present in whole file.

So this output only comes when we do not pass any option to `wc`, in case you need to get these details very specifically then use something like: `wc -l` to get lines and `wc -c` to get number of characters in Input_file.

***From `man wc`:***

> DESCRIPTION
>          Print  newline,  word,  and  byte counts for each FILE, and a total line if more than one FILE is specified.  With no FILE, or when
>   FILE is -, read standard
>          input.  A word is a non-zero-length sequence of characters delimited by white space.  The options below may be used to  select 
>   which  counts  are  printed,
>          always in the following order: newline, word, character, byte, maximum line length.